# Count a list of cells with the same background color

Tags: excel, vba

Each cell contains some text and a background color. So I have some cells that are blue and some that are red. What function do I use to count the number of red cells?

I have tried `=COUNTIF(D3:D9,CELL("color",D3))` with no success (Where `D3` is red).

Answer (score 10):

Excel has no way of gathering that attribute with it's built-in functions. If you're willing to use some VB, all your color-related questions are answered here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx

Example form the site:

> The SumColor function is a color-based
>   analog of both the SUM and SUMIF
>   function. It allows you to specify
>   separate ranges for the range whose
>   color indexes are to be examined and
>   the range of cells whose values are to
>   be summed. If these two ranges are the
>   same, the function sums the cells
>   whose color matches the specified
>   value. For example, the following
>   formula sums the values in B11:B17
>   whose fill color is red.
>
> `=SUMCOLOR(B11:B17,B11:B17,3,FALSE)`

Answer (score 6):

The worksheet formula, `=CELL("color",D3)` returns `1` if the cell is formatted with color for negative values (else returns `0`).

You can solve this with a bit of VBA. Insert this into a VBA code module:

```
Function CellColor(xlRange As Excel.Range)
    CellColor = xlRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then use the function `=CellColor(D3)` to display the `.ColorIndex` of `D3`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. The color index is coming out to 55 when there are 6 cells with the color.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite complete my explanation. ColorIndex specifies an index value into the current colour palette, so you will need another worksheet formula to count how many CellColor functions return 55.

Comment: Here is detailed step by step article with pictures about creating user defined function in VBA add-in:

Count The Number of Cells With Specific Cell Color By Using VBA https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384

Comment: Beware that `ColorIndex` is [limited to tiny 64 colors palette](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296089%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) while [Color property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840719.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may [change values between Excel versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173644/vba-excel-range-of-rgb-for-colorindex-compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

I just created this and it looks easier. You get these 2 functions:

```
=GetColorIndex(E5)  <- returns color number for the cell
```

from (cell)

```
=CountColorIndexInRange(C7:C24,14) <- returns count of cells C7:C24 with color 14
```

from (range of cells, color number you want to count)

example shows percent of cells with color 14

```
=ROUND(CountColorIndexInRange(C7:C24,14)/18, 4 )
```

Create these 2 VBA functions in a Module (hit Alt-F11)

open + folders. double-click on Module1

Just paste this text below in, then close the module window (it must save it then):

```
Function GetColorIndex(Cell As Range)
  GetColorIndex = Cell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function

Function CountColorIndexInRange(Rng As Range, TestColor As Long)
  Dim cnt
  Dim cl As Range
  cnt = 0

  For Each cl In Rng
    If GetColorIndex(cl) = TestColor Then
      Rem Debug.Print ">" & TestColor & "<"
      cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
  Next

  CountColorIndexInRange = cnt

End Function
```

Comment: How can I make this solution to work automatic calculation when I change some background colour manually after the formula was in place? For now it is working fine for me, but I have to re-enter the formulas to re-count the new values after the colours has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I was needed to solve absolutely the same task. I have divided visually the table using different background colors for different parts. Googling the Internet I've found this page https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue because ColorIndex refers to some unpredictable value, so if some cells have nuances of one color (for example different values of brightness of the color), the suggested function counts them. The solution below is my fix:

```
Function CountBgColor(range As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim cell As range
    Dim color As Long
    color = criteria.Interior.color
    For Each cell In range
        If cell.Interior.color = color Then
            CountBgColor = CountBgColor + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes VBA is the way to go.

But, if you don't need to have a cell with formula that auto-counts/updates the number of cells with a particular colour, an alternative is simply to use the 'Find and Replace' function and format the cell to have the appropriate colour fill.

Hitting 'Find All' will give you the total number of cells found at the bottom left of the dialogue box.

[image]

This becomes especially useful if your search range is massive. The VBA script will be very slow but the 'Find and Replace' function will still be very quick.