# Counting an excel cell if it is filled with a colour

Tags: excel

If i have 500 cells filled with red, 500 filled with green and 50 filled with yellow, is it possible to do a countif sorta formula where i will have a cell which will count the number of red cells, green cells and yellow.

thanks

Edit - Also is it possible count the value of the cell say if i want to count cells containing Jones and the cell is RED.

Comment: Sorry think i have put this in the wrong forum.

Comment: SO does handle quite a few Excel questions... let it percolate for a bit.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964/count-a-list-of-cells-with-the-same-background-color. Please try the VBA referenced there.

Comment: Rajah i shifted it from stackoverflow as i it wasnt a coding question.

Comment: Au contraire, @user445714, the only solutions I see out there involve Excel (VBA) programming. Not only is your question appropriate to SO, it has been asked (and answered) before.

Comment: I have another extended part for this question do I re ask the question or just drop it in here. I will ask here anyways - if i want to countif cells which contain a Name say jones and the cell colour is red

Comment: @user445714 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2893/discussion-between-rajah9-and-user445714)

Comment: Never re-ask a question; always edit your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this [Ozgrid page](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27182&highlight=count%20color) and examine the VBA code. If you type in (or copy and paste) the ColorFunction, it will count how many things there are of the color of the first argument. This one worked perfectly out of the box.

I changed one line from

```
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
```

to

```
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol And rCell.Value = "Jones" Then
```

and was able to have it count only the Red cells that had "Jones" in them. But I would recommend that you alter the ColorFunction to take an additional parameter (namely, the string to be searched for) instead of hard-coding "Jones".