# VBA Excel: Range of RGB for Colorindex compatibility

Tags: excel, vba, colors, rgb

I have a macro created **in Excel 2007** which lets a value depend on the font color of a source file, as follows (this piece of code is part of a loop):

```
 If Worksheets("Source1").Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165) Or Worksheets("Source1").Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(117, 146, 60) Then
     Worksheets("Result").Cells(UnusedRow, 15).Value = "Closed"
 Else
     Worksheets("Result").Cells(UnusedRow, 15).Value = "Active"
 End If
```

This works without a problem.

However, strangely enough the *same* cells in the *same* source file have different RGB values when opened **with Excel 2013**: RGB(165, 165, 165) in 2007 becomes RGB(166, 166, 166) in 2013, and RGB(117, 146, 60) in 2007 becomes RGB(118, 147, 60) in 2013.

That is why I thought to use a small range for every number in the font color, for instance for RGB(x, y, z) from the source file:

```
 If x => 164 And x <= 167 And y => 164 And y <= 167 And z => 164 And z <= 167 Then 
   ...
```

Can someone tell me how to code this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: If we are talking about logic, Excel shouldn't change the RGB values in the first place. This is not mapping, but defining a range for an x, y and z in RGB(x,y,z). All I need is to connect any RGB value close to RGB(165,165,165) and RGB(117,146,60) to status "Closed", so it would stop quite quickly actually.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your issue. Further, I can't find any mention of it elsewhere. Have you reduced it to a very simple test, e.g., setting the values with something like `ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)` in Excel 2007, and `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)` in Excel 2013? Doing so yields `True` for me in 2013's immediate window in both cases.

Comment: I just noticed that your post title refers to `ColorIndex`. Your code doesn't refer to it that I can see. The two are, of course, incompatible. They wouldn't result in the differences you're seeing, so I'm guessing it's just a typo?

Comment: The thing is that I don't have control over the source file, so I cannot set the values myself. In the source file, the user is setting the color index (manual without VBA) of the font by clicking in the color palette of Excel. Saving it in Excel 2007 and opening it in Excel 2013 leads to different RGB values.

Comment: When you open this file in Excel 2007 and check the RGB values of the font, it will be 165, 165, 165. When you open this file in Excel 2013, it will be 166, 166, 166. Who knows if it will change in future Excel versions, therefore I want to accept a small range of colors to determine the status of the cell.[link]http://www.filedropper.com/test1_3

Comment: I went to the website, but I'm pretty paranoid so did not open. However, if I create one in Excel 2007 and open in Excel 2013 I don't see what you are describing. Given the rather particular problem, I'd just check for the particular values with an OR statement. If your sure it's version-based, you can check which version of Excel is running (internet search will find that). Good luck!

    BTW, putting "@" at the beginning of a user name in one of these comments sends us a notification that you addressed something at us.

Comment: @DougGlancy: If you could check these steps: 1. Create a new 2007 file, write something in a cell and pick a grey colorindex manually for the font. 2. Check the RGB values. 3. Open the file in 2013 and check the RGB values. Do you see the difference (preferably pick the colorindex associating with 165, 165, 165)? I do not want an OR statement, because I do not know how future Excel versions will change the values and I would like to handover this macro to someone.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "grey" isn't specific enough. There's quite a few shades in among the choices and none that I see are called "gray." But I know understand your description of what's happening. Clearly it's not a good system, but that's beyond your control. I understand wanting to do a range, but RGB colors don't easily lend to that. However, if it's to be done, this post and the ones that follow it will help: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/03/04/a-suite-of-xl-color-functions-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my brain finally came up for air, and I've got an answer.

Instead of `Color`, use `ColorIndex`. That's the index of the position of the color they pick in the palette.

I'm not saying it's a great system (it's not) but given your constraint - relying on the user to click a certain color button, it's as good as you're going to get.

I think.

Comment: But hang on... I don't have an excel 2007 test base so I can't check, but didn't you already disprove the behaviour claimed by the OP? Why divert from that line with this? Sorry to but in, but I'm just curious... If what the OP says is true then its valuable information.

Comment: @CoolBlue. The `ColorIndex` property refers to the 50-or-so colors in the palette that appears when you go to change a font color. The `Color` property refers to an RGB. Yes, it is true that a cell set to an RGB (`Color`) in one file will have the same RGB in other versions. However the palette colors are customizable (Options>Save>Colors), so a ColorIndex's RGB can vary from user to user or computer to computer. And maybe MS changed them from version to version. At any rate, you can't count on the same position (`ColorIndex`) being the same RGB. So, I'd just check the `ColorIndex` (position).

Comment: ah, OK, it was clear as mud until you put that comment.  The other possibility is to make a rough calculation of the variance in the three RGB numbers.  If they are more or less the same then you have a black and white shade (e.g. 16X,16X,16X).  If there is a big "variance" then its colorful (e.g. 118,14X,60).

Comment: @DougGlancy This is would be an option (and I am considering it), but think of the following situation: Microsoft decides that future Excel versions will have a bigger color palette (for instance, an extra column of colors) and the ColorIndex will therefore not match anymore. However, the font color in the source file should still be somewhere around RGB(16x, 16x, 16x) or RGB(11x, 14x, 60). Wouldn't a range around x, y, z be the safest way to go?

Comment: I can think of many situations where this system can go wrong. I do think the above answers the problem you're seeing now. In terms of future-proofing, I suggest you get them to add a "Status" column to the file, preferably with some data validation. Otherwise, sure, look at the link I mentioned and try to capture a range, but I don't see how you can place much confidence in it. Good luck!