# If cell is highlight then

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table and I want to get a count of the number of cells in a row that are highlighted?

I have tried looking for a formula. I tried getting a COUNT-IF against a colored cell.

I'm guessing you will need some sort of V.B.A. code since there's no formula (Otherwise I wouldn't be here)

Any option to get a count of highlighted cells?

Comment: You can you use 'Filter' to only show the highlighted rows, that might be one way to solve the problem for you....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count a list of cells with the same background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964/count-a-list-of-cells-with-the-same-background-color)

Comment: @MichaelHudson that wont work as it the highlighted cells are scattered through the table. Filtering will miss some of that data

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a straight forward formula like vlookup, sum, countif ect. so unfortunately it requires a macro.

Create a macro and here is the code I used:

```
Sub COUNT_HIGHLIGHTS()
'
' COUNT_HIGHLIGHTS
'


'Defining variables
Dim LastRow As Long, Count As Integer


'Getting a number value for the number of rows in the table (as this can vary on table size)
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


'For loop to loop through rows
For i = 2 To LastRow
'Count is the number of cells in the row which are highlighted
Count = 0
'For loop for cells within the row (My table always has 36 cells)
For j = 5 To 36
'If statement to check if cell is highlighted
If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535 Then
'Add +1 to count ever time a highlighted cell is found
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next j
'find cell at the end of the row and add the count
Cells(i, 37).Select
Selection.Value = Count
Next i
End Sub
```

Once you finish you get a column at the end

Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | ...... Column just outside your table
ColValue 1 | ColValue2| ColValue3| ....... 5 (If 5 cells in the table are highlighted)

Then just filter the table to the count values you created to everything but 0

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use a UDF (User Defined Function) for that. Here is one. It will count all cells which are not without colour, regardless of which colour they have.

```
Function HighLightCount(Target As Range) As Integer
    ' 14 Feb 2018

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Fun As Integer

    For Each Cell In Target
        Fun = Fun - Int(Cell.Interior.Color <> 16777215)
    Next Cell
    HighLightCount = Fun
End Function
```

Install the code in a standard code module (by default that would be `Module1` until you change the name). Call the function from the worksheet like a normal Excel function, for example,

```
=HighLightCount(A2:J2)
```

You can copy/paste the formula to other cells just like any other. You can also embed it in Excel's built-in functions, for example,

```
=IF(HighLightCount(A6:J6)>2,SUM(A6:D6),SUM(E6:J6))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search cells by specific color the below UDF will help you.

```
Function CountCellsByColor(SearchRange As Range, RefCellColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = RefCellColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In SearchRange
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

`SearchRange` is your range where you are searching and `RefCellColor` is reference cell of which color format you are looking in `SearchRange`.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way to do this without VBA - however it is very messy, and you need both a "working" row and an Excel4 macro in a Named Range.  I detail it only for completeness.

Step 1:  Create a Named Range called "Background_Below" (FORMULAS > NAME MANAGER) and give it followin Refers To: `=GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("r[-1]c",FALSE))`

Step 2:  Add a working row on the row **below** the row you want to count highlighted cells in, and put the formula `=Background_Below` in the row.  This will be 0 for "no colour" or >0 for "colour"  (The actual value will be the closest `xlColorIndex` value to the colour of the cell above)

Step 3:  Do a `COUNTIF` where the Working Row is >0

As I said, it's messy - at least 9-times-out-of-10 you would be better off using a User Defined Function in VBA.  But it is possible