# Excel VBA Macro while column doesn't contain at least one red cell

Tags: vba, excel, count

I am writing a macro to sort a table of numerical data based on values in the columns. If the value is within 5% of the max value of the column it is colored yellow using cell.interior.color index = 6. I want to iterate through and each iteration find the row with the MAX number of yellow cells, and then highlight them red. This will be iterated until each column contains at least one red cell. I have code to highlight based on this criteria, but am missing a while statement for each column not containing a red cell. I am also looking for a way to break a tie if two rows have the same max number of yellow cells. This tie would be broken by choosing the max number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'COUNT ROWS IN TABLE

Dim numrows As Long, myTable As ListObject, myworksheet As Worksheet
Set myworksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myTable = myworksheet.ListObjects("Table1")
numrows = myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

'MsgBox numrows

'COUNT YELLOW PER ROW
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To numrows + 3
    For j = 2 To 12 'columns
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 Then
            Range("M" & i).Value = Range("M" & i).Value + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Dim rowc As Range

If Cells(4, "Q") = 1 Then
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    For k = 4 To numrows + 3 'row
        For l = 3 To 12 'col
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, l).Select
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(k, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And Cells(k, 16).Value = 1 Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(k, l).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next l
    Next k
Else: For Each rowc In Range("P4:P" & numrows + 3)

If Cells(rowc, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And Cells(rowc, "C") = Cells    ("C2") Then
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Next rowc
```

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: have a look at [Using COUNTIF with colors](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011725_Using_COUNTIF_with_Colors.html) and [Count the number of cells with specific colors using VBA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2815384/count-the-number-of-cells-with-specific-cell-color-by-using-vba)

Comment: and here is another one I found (using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+count+coloured+cells&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)): [How to count and sum cells based on background color in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1155-excel-count-sum-cells-by-color.html)

Comment: Thanks for the references. For this specific example however, I am looking for a way to use a while loop to continue highlighting and counting cells. New to VBA entirely but have programming logic experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count a list of cells with the same background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964/count-a-list-of-cells-with-the-same-background-color)

Comment: I have the count of colored cells, however I am looking to do further logic with this count. My description explains this.

Comment: have a look at [Excel While Loops](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=122:excel-vba-loops-with-examples-for-loop-do-while-loop-do-until-loop&catid=79&Itemid=475) and [https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-while-loop/](VBA While Loop - A complete guide)

Comment: I am still looking for more specific syntax of how to check if a column contains one or more colored cell. I can only get it to check one cell or if the entire column is colored.

Comment: you could create an [array variable](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) and add to it for each coloured cell in the column?

Comment: cArray(g, f) = Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex is not working, it says subscript out of range

Comment: @TomExcel1017 You have numerous errors in your code. Try to fix them one by one, tell which error message you get and in which line. There is at least one `End If` missing and there is a `Next rowc` but no `For rowc` in the code. Also your first `If` statement is incomplete and should throw an error. Start by understanding the error messages and fix all these errors first.

Comment: Apologies for those errors, I believe my code was working and may have only grabbed a small snippet of it where the issue was. I am still looking for a while loop to iterate while each column in a table does not contain at least one red cell, and a way to use an if else when two rows contain the same amount of yellow cells per my question statement.